# Bad Request Error OpenStack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I am trying to create an Instance from command line using the command,

```
nova boot --config-drive=true --flavor 2 --key-name key1 --image c28bc1e8-a25f-413c-9e13-fecdd5d6f522 instance1
```

But I got this error,

> ERROR (BadRequest): Network 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,
>   11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 could not be found. (HTTP 400)
>   (Request-ID: req-6dd0352e-008a-40c4-91e2-454529712ba9)

Guide me how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m guessing you may have the `rax_default_network_flags_python_novaclient_ext` Python package installed, which automatically adds those networks to the request, but are not booting an instance in the Rackspace public cloud.

This can likely be resolved using the `--no-service-ne`t and `--no-public arguments`, or by uninstalling the above mentioned Python module.

Comment: There is no such command installed, but --no-service-net and --no-public command works for me, thanks for your help